# node js get text from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am a beginner with Node js. I have the following html:

```
<div id="items" class="row"> 
  <dl class="col">
            <dt>Year</dt>
            <dd><strong>2010</strong></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

I then use the code below to get ´2010´ from ´strong´ element.

```
classes=[];

request(url, function (error, response, data) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    $("#items dl dd strong" ).each(function(){
      var hej = $(this).attr('text'); //
      classes.push(hej);


    });
    console.log(classes);
};
});
```

But that does not work obviosly... Any ideas?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is not an attribute. You probably want to call jQuery's `text()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/text/